# How to make preg_match to find whole word but not separate hyphen-words?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, text-parsing

```
if (preg_match('#\b'.$rawword.'\b#i',$body)) {
```

This code finds whole words, but if they are a hyphen word like "ABLE-BODIED" it will find ABLE and BODIED separately. How can modify the expression to accommodate for the dash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookbehind and lookahead operators. This operators looks in behind and after but not match them.

for example use `\b(?<!-)xyz(?!-)\b` for finding whole words of `xyz` that doesn't have `-` before or after.

Comment: just for everyone's sake what does the (?<!)   (?!*) mean exactly - or what do those characters do?

Comment: @user723220 Those are lookbehind and lookahead assertions, respectively, cumulatively known as [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). They detect whether or not a pattern exists before or after a string without actually matching anything. (They're "zero-width," thus the term "assertion.")

Comment: hmm that seems to have killed my preg_match

Comment: if (preg_match('#\b(?<!-)$rawword(?!-)\b#i',$body)) {

Comment: @user723220 In `'#\b(?<!-)$rawword(?!-)\b#i'`, you're now trying to use variable replacement in a single-quoted string, which won't work. Append like you did before or use double quotes. [PHP string ref](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: if (preg_match('#\b(?<!-)'.$rawword.'(?!-)\b#i',$body)) {   

Got it to work - misplaced quotes. So, to summarize, this code finds whole words in a string, but doesn't count whole words if they have a "-" (dash) adjacent to the word. Thanks to Wiseguy

Comment: @user723220 Read literally, that expression means "a word boundary, followed by `$rawword` that doesn't have a hyphen before it nor a hyphen after it, followed by a word boundary." If `$rawword` is found with a hyphen after it, regex processor continues on until it finds one that doesn't have a following hyphen.

Comment: Are you want to search for 'SOMEWORD' and find it in 'SOMEWORD-' but not in 'SOMEWORD-S'?

Comment: And if your answer is yes, what about 'SOMEWORD--'?

Comment: Try using this regex: `\b(?<!-)xyz(?!\w|-\w)`. This would match 'xyz', 'xyz-', 'xyz--' but not '-xyz', 'xyz-f'.